# What is intracellular retention?

Tags: terminology, definitions, cytoskeleton

On the wiki page for [proto-cadherins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocadherin), they write, "The cytoplasmic domain also mediates intracellular retention, a property which distinguishes the clustered protocadherins from the related classical cadherins." citing the following [source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2646808/).

Unfortunately, I was unable to find much anything to go off. Anyone know off-hand what this terminology is referencing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this line from the paper you linked, it seems like they are using intracellular retention to refer to proto-cadherins being taken up in to the cell via endocytosis.

> It is possible that the effects of deleting the intracellular domain might be a result of loss of an organelle retention signal located in the cytoplasmic domain of the protein and/or a decrease in endocytosis of the protein accumulated in the membrane.

This paper also refers to intracellular retention of cadherins in the context of endocytosis of proto-cadherins: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3216661/

Based on this information, the quote from the Wikipedia page ("The cytoplasmic domain also mediates intracellular retention, a property which distinguishes the clustered protocadherins from the related classical cadherins.") seems to be saying that the cytoplasmic domain regulates proto-cadherins on the cell membrane being taken back up into the cell via endocytosis, hence retaining them intracellularly.

Comment: Thanks, man. My understanding of your answer is that for proto-cadherins downregulation is via the endocytosis process. As to what happens after endocytosis? Lysosomal degradation? So how would this compare to the up-and-down regulation of non-proto-cadherins? What benefits arise from one mechanism relative to the other?

Comment: I'm not too sure, I'd have to do some reading. It might be worth asking another question about that to get a good answer.